# How to design a backend for Polymer?

Tags: server-side

I've been watching Google I/O and I have decided to try to build a small scale site with Polymer. I have some HTML,CSS & JS knowledge, but I don't have much knowledge about programming the backend, so I would like to learn some of that in the process as well. 
The problem is I'm not quite sure how to approach this. When it comes to backend I'm mostly used to the server responding to requests with HTML files or so such as in PHP and I've been reading a bit about REST APIs and JSON. Also, at Google I/O they talked a lot about firebase, but I would like to create my own backend for educational purposes.

So my question is, what approach should be used for backend for polymer applications ? What is recommended ? Is there any particular language that should be used ? Should the server be returning HTML or JSON ? I'm looking for the right approach thst could be used also for a backend that could serve an android app as well as the web app in the future maybe.

I tried googling but since I don't have much experience in this area , the results hasn't been very rewarding. I would badically just like to be pointed in the right direction, I know there's usually no straight answer for this.

Comment: Check [the latest release of the CUBA Platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com/blog/whats-new-in-cuba-platform-6-4#polymer-ui) seamlessly integrating Polymer with CUBA (java) backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest and fastest way to start would be using [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/), [tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/). This is a JavaScript library that runs on the server.

 If you're looking for compiled languages, then you could look at  Java with [Apache tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)

 As for the return format, I would definitely go with JSON and perform a the dedicated formatting on the client (you mentioned you want to support multiple clients)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is pretty much what I was hoping to hear. I think I'll dig into Node.js for now , as I am a bit tired of Java from school at the moment. For the future , are there any languages / frameworks that should NOT be used for Polymer web app backends ? Or it really doesn't matter if I'm going for REST and JSON ?

Comment: @Near I would say it's purely a matter of developer's preference. Unless they're additional considerations like performance or security. In such cases you'd have to choose a language that supports additional requirements

Answer (score 0):

The fastest implementation of a backend with polymer i've done is to use ***firebase*** (serverless architecture). because firebase already made webcomponents to connect backend data to your polymer front. it's simple as two html tag:

```
// connect your client to get firebase `fireRef` object
<firebase-app
    app="{{fireRef}}
    name="firebaseApp"
    api-key="YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"
    auth-domain="YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN_HERE"
    database-url="YOUR_DATABASE_URL_HERE">
</firebase-app>

// use `fireRef` to interact with backend data with a given path
<firebase-document
    app="[[fireRef]]"
    path="/users/[[userId]]"
    data="{{user}}">
</firebase-document>
```

then you got a `user` property filled/synced with your backend data.

For a simple project this solution doesn't require any backend code.